# can't read the token even though it exists

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, authorization

My website is showing a not valid message which it should show when there is no token and i can show user posts,
even though I can print the token in the console

This is the token creation code:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const generateToken = (id) => {
    return jwt.sign({ id }, `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`, {
        expiresIn: "30d",
    });
};
```

this is verifying token code:

```
import User from "../models/User.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header("Authorization")

        if(!token) return res.status(500).json({msg: "Not Valid!"})

        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESSTOKENSECRET)
        if(!decoded) return res.status(500).json({msg: "Not Valid!"})

        const user = await User.findOne({_id: decoded.id})
        req.user = user;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
    }
}

export default auth;
```

Is there a way to import the token into the frontend ?

I think I'll try my best if I can,

Like storing the token in the localStorage

Answer (score 1):

You should create a user login API to let user login and and return a token to frontend via http response. Then the frontend js store the token into cookie or localStorage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).